# Using Terraform to create a cloudwatch alert (metric_alarm). How can I use alarm_actions for an individual host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform

The [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_metric_alarm.html) covers cloudwatch alarms in the context of autoscaling groups, but not individual instances.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "foobar" {
  alarm_name                = "terraform-test-foobar5"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
  ...
  dimensions {
    InstanceId = "${aws_instance.myOrg-myHost.id}"
  }

  alarm_description = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization"
  #This would be for autoscaling
  #alarm_actions     = ["${aws_autoscaling_policy.bat.arn}"]
}
```

I'm guessing it will be something like:

```
alarm_actions = ["arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:MyTopic"]
```

Comment: Humm, that seemed to work. Weird that I can't find it documented anywhere though.

Answer (score 3):

There are documents, but not in terraform.

For dimensions, aws has all documents at here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CW_Support_For_AWS.html

If you need to find out the dimensions for instances (`EC2`), the document is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html

In the last part, the document mentions there are 4 dimensions you can use, and seems you found it out already.

```
AutoScalingGroupName
ImageId
InstanceId
InstanceType
```